# Update field based on condition met in a row

Tags: sql, sql-update

May I confirm the syntax to update the employee code (for all PM lines) to be the VP for each corresponding client?

```
Client  Type    Level   Employee Code
9702    VP       P          11
9702    PM       P          XXXX
9703    VP       P          12
9703    PM       P          XXXX
```

I need it to look like below

```
Client  Type    Level   Employee Code
9702    VP       P          11
9702    PM       P          11
9703    VP       P          12
9703    PM       P          12
```

Comment: If you want us to confirm the syntax it would help if you actually posted the statement you want to confirm.

Comment: Sorry JPW. I don't know the statement. I used "Syntax" in the issue to refer to the statement. I thought it would be better to describe in plain English what I was trying to do do.

Comment: Shouldn't the last row in your sample results have Employee Code 12 as PM?

Comment: yes..sorry. not a good first post

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good question, I could have sworn it was tagged as MySQL at some point which was why I adapted my answer to MySQL. The revision history says nothing about MySQL though...

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have access to any MySQL server at the moment I wasn't able to test this, but if memory serves me right the syntax for MySQL to update from a joined table should look something like this:

```
UPDATE `your_table` a 
JOIN `your_table` b ON a.`Client` = b.`Client` AND b.`Type` = 'VP'
SET a.`Employee Code` = b.`Employee Code`
WHERE a.`Type` = 'PM'
```

For MS SQL Server the syntax would be this:

```
UPDATE a
SET [Employee Code] = b.[Employee Code]
FROM your_table a 
JOIN your_table b ON a.Client = b.Client AND b.Type = 'VP'
WHERE a.Type = 'PM'
```

Comment: I run the following code and it says incorrect syntax near the first a (alias for prj_emp_resp_listing)

update prj_emp_resp_listing a
join prj_emp_resp_listing b on a.prj_code = b.prj_code and a.resp_type_code = 'PA'
set a.emp_code_resp = b. emp_code_resp
where a.resp_type_code = 'PM

Comment: @james I'm assuming you used the MySQL version? It should work, take a look at this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/daacf0/1

Comment: @james But what database are you actually using? Is it MySQL or something else?